# Is it possible to deploy actors to cluster without a router

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka.net

I'm prototyping an actor system which has parent and child actors.  I want all of  my child actors to be deployed remotely to a specific cluster role.  I have 1..n parents and each parent has 1..n children.  New instances are created/deployed as the system is running based on incoming messages.

I have the following actor paths, although based on my question I may not be modeling this correctly.

- /user/parents/ -> factory for creating/addressing specific parent actors
- /user/parents/{parentId} -> one instance per parent, deployed to 'main' cluster role
- /user/parents/{parentId}/{childId} -> one per child, deployed to 'other' cluster role

I have been unable to find documentation or examples for deploying to clusters without using group or pool routers.

**How can I deploy child actors to a cluster (role 'other')?**

Comment: It seems to be possible to do this using Akka.NET's remoting ([see docs](http://getakka.net/docs/remoting/deployment)), though I don't know how this can be applied to a cluster.

However I imagine that cluster routers use this mechanism under the hood somehow to do this. Perhaps digging around in the source repo will yield the answers you need.